# Conditional Inner Join based on Content of primary Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to run through a program to check if vouchers are valid within a vouchers table.

There are some simple validation aspect such as whether the voucher has passed expiry date or not, but also, some vouchers might be conditional based upon a customer buying specific products by brand, or supplier.

So, I have table of vouchers

```
    id    |     brand     |     supplier    |    value    etc
```

a table of brands

```
   id     |      name       etc
```

and a table of suppliers

```
   id     |     name     etc
```

If a voucher is not specific to a  brand or supplier, then the value in the vouchers tale is `0`

I have tried this Sql query inner joining the tables, but I get no results, I am assuming this is because the voucher code (id) I am trying to use is not specific to a brand or supplier?

```
SELECT *, brands.name as brandName, suppliers.name as supplierName  
    FROM `vouchers` 
    INNER JOIN brands on vouchers.brand = brands.id 
    INNER JOIN suppliers on vouchers.supplier = suppliers.id 
    WHERE vouchers.id= '" & voucherCode & "'
```

How would I write this so that the joining of the table `brands` is conditional upon the value `brand` in the table `vouchers` is greater than 0 (and then simiarly for suppliers)

I have had a look on here and see several other questions posted, but I am afraid I don't fully understand the answers to e able to relate them to my situation.

Using MySQL database by the way :-)

Comment: Why would you do a conditional join? Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. If you receive null-records, that means no results have been found for a particular record. Then apply logic in your application, if not null - brands have been found, if null - no brands. Don't employ logic on the database layer.

Comment: In answer to this, simply because I am rubbish with Sql!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do a `LEFT JOIN` instead like this:

```
SELECT *, brands.name as brandName, suppliers.name as supplierName  
    FROM `vouchers` 
    LEFT JOIN brands on vouchers.brand = brands.id 
    LEFT JOIN suppliers on vouchers.supplier = suppliers.id 
    WHERE vouchers.id= '" & voucherCode & "'
```

This will return all the `vouchers` no matter if they have `brands` or `suppliers`

Comment: @Jamie Hartnoll : remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to return valid vouchers, try:

```
SELECT *, brands.name as brandName, suppliers.name as supplierName  
FROM `vouchers` 
LEFT JOIN brands on vouchers.brand = brands.id 
LEFT JOIN suppliers on vouchers.supplier = suppliers.id 
WHERE vouchers.id= '" & voucherCode & "' and
      vouchers.brand = coalesce(brands.id, 0) and
      vouchers.supplier = coalesce(suppliers.id, 0)
```